# Prove $R^{\times} \not=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Let $(R, +, \cdot)$ be a commutative ring with $1$.

How can you prove, that $R^{\times} \not=R$ ?

Idea:
Since (by its definition) $R^{\times}$ only consists of all elements ($xu = ux = 1$) that divide 1 , $R^{\times}$ can never be $R$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $0\notin R^\times$

Comment: what is the purpose under this question?

Comment: Example:$R=\mathbb{Z_5}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $R^{\times}=\{1,3,2,4\}$

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 I believe it is to verify the argument for proof that the OP has given. It can't just be to produce an example where $R^\times = R$.

Comment: If you consider {0} a ring you have an example

Comment: I think the more interesting question would be to investigate whether the abelian groups $R^\times$ and $(R,+)$ can be isomorphic. They cannot be if $R$ is a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since (by its definition) $R^{\times}$ only consists of all elements ($xu = ux = 1$) that divide 1 , $R^{\times}$ can never be $R$.

This is slightly incomplete, because you also need to use the fact that $R$ contains $1$. This is usually taken to mean that $R$ contains $1$, *which is not equal to $0$*. In particular, $0$ is not in $R^\times$. Hence, $R^\times \neq R.$

If we do not make this assumption then $R$ can be equal to $R^\times$, as is the case for the trivial ring $R = \{ 0 \}$.